# Class named 'Manifest' and Intellij IDEA

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm having a weird problem with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. Consider a project, which consists of an android application module and android library module. Application module depends on a library module and a bunch of external .jar files.

The library module has a class named 'Manifest', and an instance of this class is created in the application module. When I compile and run the project I get an exception during runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.entities.Manifest
at com.example.ManifestProvider.getManifest(ManifestProvider.java:94)
...
```

Where `getManifest` just calls a constructor of a `Manifest` class.

This project was imported from Eclipse, where it works just fine. Every other part of the project works fine when running from IDEA as well. And the weird thing is that if I rename `Manifest` class to something else, say, `Manifest2` then the whole project works fine from IDEA. Renaming it back to `Manifest` brings the exception back as well.

Unfortunately I can't rename the class and leave it be, because it's referenced from a lot of places and the rest of the team won't support my decision in doing so.

Is that some kind of an issue with IDEA? Is there any kind of workaround?

Comment: Are you sure that the library is being packaged into the APK? You can check the contents of the APK to see if the class is in there. I'm guessing not.

Comment: In the output directory I can see only 'classes' folder, AndroidManifest.xml, R.txt and library's .jar file. Jar file contains every class from the library including the `Manifest.class`.

Comment: There should be an APK that is built by IntelliJ. It may be in the "bin" folder or the root folder of the project and not in the "output" directory.

Comment: By an output directory I meant the "bin" directory. And it has no .apk file in it.

Comment: Well, if you build the application, IntelliJ creates an APK. Search your disk to find it.

Comment: Silly me, I was looking for an .apk of a library, which isn't created. Application's .apk file, on the other hand, has classes.dex, which in turn has `Manifest.class` in it.